# Package 'Microsoft SQL Management Studio Package' failed to load

Tags: sql-server-2008

All of a sudden  today, Sql Server Management Studio refuses to load and open.
and got the error "Package 'Microsoft SQL Management Studio Package' failed to load".The configurations of the system are as follows:

- Windows Server 2008 and x64
- Sql Server 2008

Since this is the production environment can any one please give us a good solution ASAP?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions.After windows updates the production machine has not been restarted for few days,rebooting the machine solved the problem.